# Virtualbox user home directory

Tags: virtualbox

I have a tiny problem. I want to avoid VirtualBox from creating `/home/$USER/.VirtualBox` directory and create another directory like `/home/$USER/DIR` instead to put the log files etc there. I tried to export `$VBOX_USER_HOME` variable in my `.bashrc` so it is set in my shell and also used the `vboxmanage setproperty machinefolder /home/amin/DIR` command but VirtualBox still creates `.VirtualBox` directory under `/home/$USER`. 
Is there any other way to achive this or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around it thusly:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/my/custom/dotVirtualBox
mv .VirtualBox/* /path/to/my/custom/dotVirtualBox/
rmdir .VirtualBox
ln -s /path/to/my/custom/dotVirtualBox .VirtualBox
```

Answer (score 2):

There is several ways to go about this, you can link the directory to something you like as @DopeGhoti suggest, but what works for me is set the default machine folder using `Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager`: go to Menu `File` → `Preferences` and select `General` there it says `Default Machine Folder`.

If you have already created VM, you can move them, but not just by moving the files, there is a description on [how to move VM machines](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=55003) the proper way (if you setup the soft-link, you don't have that problem).